# How to not display Android application Name on every screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am finding that in my Android application, the name of the application is displaying on the top of every screen, consuming a line of valuable screen real estate.

I am using LinearLayouts

How can I get this not to display?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set it in the Activity/Application tags in the manifest XML:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

See more here ([Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)).

Answer (score 6):

Or write in onCreate yours Activity before setContentView():

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 3):

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".A"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

you can add this line android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" to the manifest and make your application fullscreen and without title bar
and if you want to remove only the title bar and don't want to make the application full screen then you can use Theme.NoTitleBar

Answer (score 2):

Change your activities' theme like that

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

*android:theme="@style/AppTheme"*

Above change in Manifest file didn't work for me.

*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)*

For this to work in your project you have to make one more change. Make your acivity extends *Activity* instead of *AppCompactActivity* which comes by default.

Thank You.